# How do you fill a table with consecutive letters by specifying the starting letter?

Tags: tables, macros

What do I use for the ***function*** in the following:

```
\newcommand{\nextletters}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\function{#1} & \function{#1+1} & \function{#1+2} & \function{#1+3}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

such that

```
\nextletters{A}
```

will result in the following:

**A B C D**

while

```
\nextletters{H}
```

will result in the following:

**H I J K**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the primitive `\char`.  It takes a number and converts it to a character.  On the other hand to convert a character to a number, simply prefix `` ` ``.  To evaluate mathematical expressions use `\numexpr...\relax`.  So all in all you get `` \char\numexpr`#1\relax ``.

Of course this has unintended side effects as you reach the end of the alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\function[1]{\char\numexpr`#1\relax}

\newcommand{\nextletters}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\function{#1} & \function{#1+1} & \function{#1+2} & \function{#1+3}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\nextletters{A}

\nextletters{H}

\nextletters{Y}

\end{document}
```

[image]